# main code besides tornado webserver

Tags: tornado

I am using tornado to make a websever which has to show live data to all the connected clients which request the html page.

I use the following working code:

```
import datetime
import time
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import sys
import os.path

import binascii
import struct

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     print "[HTTP](MainHandler) User Connected."
     self.render("stack_073.html")

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

  def check_origin(self, origin):
     return True

  def open(self):
     while 1:
        self.write_message(data)
        print data
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    app = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler),
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
    ]))
    app.listen(80)
    main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    print "Tornado Server started"
    main_loop.start()

except:
    print "Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped."
```

This code works but I have put the mainloop in the open def of tornado. So when one computer is connected it stays in that loop and updates the data every second.
But what is the good way for doing this? Where do I have to put my mainloop?

Because if I put it in the good way it must be possible to connect multiple computers to the same webpage with all the same livedata.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Tornado is that it's non blocking, which means that requests that take long won't block your whole app.
However, if you use while loops in your tornado application like you did here

```
def open(self):
 while 1:
    self.write_message(data)
    print data
    time.sleep(1)
```

it is actually blocking the whole IOLoop, which is something that you don't want when using Tornado.
If you want periodic updates, implement an `on_message` method inside of your class `WSHandler`.

This method should do the following:

- listen for requests by the client (in your case, this would be the JavaScript in `stack_073.html`)
- upon a message from the client, execute the desired methods, do whatever your program should do, and then return the updated values using the `self.write_message` method.
- again, wait for a request

This will enable you to have a basic interaction between client and server, which will be non blocking, since every new connection will create a new instance of `WSHandler`.

Of course, your timer should be implemented purely inside your client, so that the JavaScript is receiving updates, then waits, and send a new update request. (In JS, you can do stuff like this with `setInterval()`)

What's important is that Tornado is communicating over WebSockets, so the communication will happen over 3 main methods, called `open`, `on_message` and `on_close` - these will be implemented in your server's python script as well as on the client's side using JavaScript. **How** your communication is being handles is totally up to you! You can send simple strings, bytes or you can parse JSON back and forth.

For more detailed information, consider reading through the official Tornado docs, they also have a basic template to illustrate what I was talking about (together with some example code for you to implement):

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html

Comment: Oh, almost forgot: if you want all connected clients to see the same data, you can use class variables inside of your `WSHandler`.